# How to capture white spaces in a string in ANTLR?

Tags: c#, antlr, whitespace

This should be simple, but I am pulling my hair out trying to solve it.

I am trying to grab a quoted string, including the white spaces (space and tab) in the string, and record the value in a CSharp string.  However, I would also like to ignore the same whitespace (via the lexer) that is included outside the quoted string.  I have the typical WS lexer rule included, but the WS rule is taking out the white spaces when I want it (when its in a quoted string).  If I remove the {channel=HIDDEN} from the WS rule, I lose all the other whitespace and have to manually add WS everywhere between the tokens.   Any help would be greatly appreciated!   Here is my grammar:

```
program returns [KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp]
    :
      ident=IDENT {kvp.Key = ident.Text;}
      '='
      quote=quoted_ident {kvp.Value = quote.ret;}
    ;

quoted_ident returns [string ret]
    :
      '"'
      (
        (ident=IDENT|ident=DOUBLE) {$ret += ident.Text;}
        |
        ws=WS {$ret += ws.Text;}
      )+
      '"'
    ;

WS :
    (
      ' '
      |
      '\t'
    )
    { $channel = HIDDEN; }
    ;

fragment DIGIT: '0'..'9';
fragment LETTER: ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z');
fragment DOT:'.';
DOUBLE : ((DIGIT)+(DOT(DIGIT)+)?)|(DOT(DIGIT)+);
IDENT : (LETTER|DIGIT|DOT|':'|'\''|'/'|'\\'|'_'|'@'|';'|'?'|'-'|'#'|'$'|'%'|'^'|'&'|'*')+;
```

Examples:

input: '  Name    = " My Name "       '

Expected Value for kvp.Value ' My Name '

Actual Value 'MyName'

I want to ignore all spaces and tabs outside of the quotes, but capture them within the quotes.

Comment: You don't have whitespace included in your grammar...

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean.  If I add 
whitespace returns [string ret]
 :
 (
   ' ' {$ret = " ";}
   |
   '\t' {$ret = "\t";}
 )
 ;
i get error(208): PublisherTemplateGrammar.g:186:1: The following token definitions can never be matched because prior tokens match the same input: WS

Comment: oh, I see now it's among your parser rules, without defining WS anywhere, can't you still achieve what you want? if not then you could create another `fragment` for whitespace, and use it in your `IDENT`